# JavaFX: Why does width computation got to do with height, and vice versa

Tags: java, javafx

From `Node.prefWidth(double height)`:

> If the node has a vertical content-bias, then callers should pass in a
>   height value that the preferred width should be based on. If the node
>   has either a horizontal or null content-bias, then the caller should
>   pass in -1.

I noticed that for other similar computational methods, I need to pass height for width calculation and width for height calculation. I read the Javadoc and still, I still don't understand why would width affects height and vice versa.

Anyone here who could explain exactly how this works?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with preserving proportions. This question seems to have some relevant discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970847/javafx-layout-content-bias-does-not-seem-to-be-able-to-cover-the-case-of-contr

Comment: Consider a label with wrapped text. The preferred height depends on the number of lines of text, which depends on the width.

Comment: Or consider something like a `FlowPane` or `TilePane` - if these are oriented horizontally, then the preferred height will depend on how much width has been assigned; if they're oriented vertically, it's the other way around.

Comment: @James_D so its purpose is for certain panes and controls which needs them? For other nodes this is simply ignored?

Comment: @Jai Sure, if they are completely independent, the implementation can just ignore the parameter. But it's fairly typical for a region to require a certain amount of *area* overall.